# use java to dump mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

I am using Ubuntu. I want to use java application to dump the MySQL database. 
Below are my code:

```
String userName = "root";
String userPassword = "root";
String oldDatabaseName = "testing";

String executeCommand = "";
executeCommand = "mysqldump -u "+userName+" -p"+userPassword+" --no-data "       
+OldDatabaseName+" > testingbackup.sql"; 

Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

if(processComplete == 0){
    System.out.println("Backup successful.");
}else{
    System.out.println("Backup failed.");
}
```

But, when I run the above program, I always get the "Backup failed" message.
Am I writing the wrong code? And what library/file I need to include in my java application? 
Any help please.

Comment: what is the output of the mysqldump process? does it succeed when you call it manually?

Comment: Can your userid create a file in the working directory, is the file `testingbackup.sql` created, if so what is in it, what is the value of `processComplete` (print it) and what OS are you running on?

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine in my windows machine.

```
   package org.some.test;

   import java.io.File;

   public class dateformat {

    private static final String dbUserName = "root";
    private static final String dbPassword = "manager";
    private static final String dbName = "opencms";

    public static void main(String[] args){

          try {
              File path =new File("D:\\dump1.sql");
                String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin/mysql", "--user=" + dbUserName, "--password=" + dbPassword,""+ dbName,"-e", "source "+path};
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete = p.waitFor();
            if (processComplete == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Restore created successfully");
                //return true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Could not restore");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you omitted a space between -p and quote:

```
-p "+userPassword+
  ^-- insert space here
```

Comment: All the MySQL user programs including `mysqldump` take *most* flags with arguments in the usual Unix/GNU way, either `--long-wordy foo` or `-x foo` as two tokens or `--long-wordy=foo` or `-xfoo` as one. But they treat password specially; ONLY the one-token forms work. IOW **WRONG**.